# Installing python modules from a memory stick without admin or cmd

Tags: python-3.x, module, pip

I have only been coding python for about a year. 
Now I am starting to use all kinds of different modules for my code.

A big problem with this is that I do most of my coding at home, where I have full access to pip. This means that I can easily install all needed modules.

However, the problem comes when I have to run the code I have made at home, at school, as I have no access to cmd, pip or admin on school computers.

I was just wondering if there was a way for me to download certain modules onto my memory stick at home, and then transfer them onto school computers without the need of cmd, pip or admin.

Answer (score 0):

To import a module in python, you must specify the python path if you want other paths to import your modules from.

For example if your path is path="/path/to/your/usb", then use the following code (If the computer allows you):

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/your/usb
$ python file.py
```

This is because USB drives are no different from different directories on the computer. I hope this helps.

Comment: @CharlieW112 you would have to have access to a cmd, do you have access to that?

Comment: I don't have access to cmd on the PC that I'm trying to install the modules on.

Comment: So you want to bypass the established security controls of the 'school's computers' without proper authorization?

Comment: Well I just wanted to know if there was a way to install python modules with all of these security controls.

Comment: You could create a virtual environment on the USB and run that environment without installing any python modules or bypassing the security controls on the school's computers.